# Set JSTL session variable when a link is pressed

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, url, struts2

I'm currently trying to create a toggle that when pressed reloads the page with the opposite of the current boolean value.

```
<s:url action="mainMenuLabelToggle" var="mainMenuToggle"></s:url> 
<a href="${mainMenuToggle}" onclick="<s:set var ="LabelToggle" value
="!#session.LabelToggle" scope="session"/>"> view without labels </a> 
<br>
```

This is the current solution that I've tried, but unfortunately it doesn't work. It seems to run the variable declaration on every page load, rather than onclick, due to the JSP portion being compiled first I think. Are there any other possible solutions? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you need the page reload or not?

Comment: Yes, I do need the page reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onclick="toggleLabel();"

<script type="text/javascript">
  function toggleLabel(){
    $.ajax("<s:url action='mainMenuLabelToggle'/>");
    document.location.reload(true);
  }
</script>
```

In the action class

```
boolean labelToggle = session.get("labelToggle");
session.put(!labelToggle);
```